# php script slow while sending email

Tags: php, html-email

I am running this script it is fine for one context but when I try this on 4 recipients it is not working just showing this error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\Hosting\8011955\html\admin\newsletter.php on line 60
```

How can I improve this code? I just want to send email not more than 200.

here is the code:

```
if(!(is_array($errors)))
{
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: \"".$from_name."\" <".$from_email.">\n";

    $query="SELECT email From newsletter WHERE visible='1'";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or mysql_error();
    while($rowdata=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $headers .= "To: \"".$to_name."\" <".$rowdata['email'].">\n";    
           mail($rowdata['email'], "$sub",$message, $headers);
    }   
}
```

Comment: And what do the logs say, mmm?

Comment: `mail()` is a slow function. you won't be able to speed it up without dumping it and switching to something better, like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PHP scripts run for 30 seconds and then stop. This value is controlled by the `max_execution_time` value in php.ini. You can override this value within the current script by calling the [`set_time_limit()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function. Each time you call `set_time_limit()` the script execution timer starts over at zero. So you can put it inside of your `while {}` loop to give your script as much time as it needs.

```
while($rowdata=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   set_time_limit(30); // Reset script timer and give script 30 seconds to send the next email
   $headers .= "To: \"".$to_name."\" <".$rowdata['email'].">\n";    
   mail($rowdata['email'], "$sub",$message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How many matching rows are in the `newsletter` table?

As an aside, there's a logical error in your code -- it will add a new `To:` field each time through the loop, so the first mail will go to:

```
To: user1@example.com
```

And the second one will go to:

```
To: user1@example.com
To: user2@example.com
```

This will result in `user1@example.com` receiving one message for every person on your mailing list, `user2@example.com` receiving one less message, and so on. Don't do this. :)

Comment: BE CAREFUL! If you do not flush out the "to" during every iteration you may end up sending the email to un-intended recipients. There was a known issue with this in the old FMail library.

Comment: ohhh thanks...i got you... will you suggest how can i improve the code. so that i can send the email to 100 contacts...

Answer (score 1):

put below line at the beginning of your function.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

this helps to run a script that needs to execute for unknown time.